# crontab doesn't run my scripts

Tags: linux, scripting

I have one script called backup.sh. what it does is simply copy file for backup.
content of file 

cp tmp/server/exception tmp/server_bck/exception_bck
cp tmp/server/bug tmp/server_bck
cp tmp/server/alarm tmp/server_bck/alarm_bck

very simple, all "cp" command.

Comment: I can run this successfully by using "./backup.sh"

Comment: Does it assume you are in a particular directory? Unless you specify, cron's working directory will be different.

Comment: I schedule the crontab like : 0 3 * * * /home/backup.sh

Comment: backup.sh and tmp folder are in the same directory

Comment: Your script needs to cd to the directory in which your files are, or alternatively you need to use absolute paths.

Comment: fixed it... thanks